# Is It Possible To Reset UI To Initial State At Runtime Without Any Direct Assignments?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to reset UI to it's initial state (the state when game started) without directly reseting elements one by one?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I'm asking for runtime. (ResetToPrefabState doesn't work at runtime.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to revert something to its initial state without manually resetting each property via script is with a scene reload. If your UI is decoupled enough, you could use Application.LoadLevelAdditive and its Unload counterpart to reload the UI as its own scene.